# EJB @Lock not working as expected

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a scheduled EJB which calls a Singleton EJB. For some reason the scheduled method executes twice on every schedule (something to do with it being referenced from a WAR file as well as in the EAR). To counter this I have put the `@Lock` annotation on the method in the `@Singleton` bean, but it still get executed twice concurrently:

```
@Stateless
public class PaymoTimer {
    @EJB
    private IPaymoManagerRemote manager;

    @Schedule(hour = "10,12,14,16", minute = "41", second = "0", info = "PaymoTimer")
    public void timer() throws Exception {
        manager.generateEmailReport();
    }
}


@LocalBean
@Singleton
public class PaymoManager implements IPaymoManagerRemote {
    @Override
    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public void generateEmailReport() {
        System.out.println("generateEmailReport");
        String text = getDailySummaryForUser();
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

My console prints out the following:

```
12:42:00,008 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 10) generateEmailReport
12:42:00,009 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) generateEmailReport
12:42:24,027 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 10) done
12:42:24,323 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 9) done
```

Looking at the times and the process ID it is clear that the method is getting called while a previous instance is still running.

Am I misunderstanding what the `@Lock` annotation is meant to do?

Comment: PaymoTimer should be a singleton, in order to create only one instance (or statefull, if one instance/client), then the timer will be executed in all current instances...

Comment: That doesn't help. Tried `@Singleton`, the timer still gets executed twice and the method is still called concurrently. (BTW `@Stateful` beans can't be scheduled)

Comment: @Lock(LockType.WRITE) ist the default behavior of all business methods on a @Singleton Bean.

if a business method is called with this behavior, then the bean is locked and other bean instances
must wait that the execution of the method is finished.

can you update your code snippet? where do you output "done"?

currently i have no idea why this does not goes in your case... i think it should...

Comment: Sorry, forgot a line. From what I understand and what you have said I shouldn't see 2 `generateEmailReport` before the first  `done`

Comment: exactly... what application server do you use? weblogic, jboss, glassfish or any other? if i have the time i want to reproduce this

Comment: Wildfly 8.1.0.Final (Kenny)

Comment: You mentioned EAR and WAR. Do you have the timer being load on two different places?

Comment: We have an EAR archive that has a JAR file with all the business logic, including the timer. And a WAR file with the web resources, that references the EJB with the timer event in it. I believe that something about this architecture causes the timer to be fired twice.

Comment: Two weeks ago I had that same problem, though my WAR wasn´t referencing my EAR. Basically my AS had somehow persisted an instance of the timer and every time I deployed my EAR, the timer was being triggered twice. I solved it by undeploying all my applications, cleaning the temporary folders from my server (*data* and *tmp* on Wildfly 9) and redeployed the applications. In your case, try first to deploy the EAR without deploying the WAR just to see if the timer is triggered correctly. Afterwards, try to deploy the WAR to see if the behavior returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that timer and singleton got packed into WAR (possible in wildfly, you basically do not need EARs anymore) as well as into the EAR. Therefore they got deployed and run twice.